# Using iterators of vector created via swig

Tags: python, swig

I'm using the std_vector.i library provided by SWIG to managed c++ vectors in python. My simplified interface file is:

```
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
 %template(MyClassVector) vector<MyClass_c>;
}
```

This are the available attributes for wrap vectors:

```
['back', 'begin', 'capacity', 'clear', 'empty', 'end', 'erase', 'front', 'get_allocator', 'insert', 'iterator', 'pop', 'pop_back', 'push_back', 'rbegin', 'rend', 'reserve', 'resize', 'size', 'this']
```

How can I use the iterator returned by the begin attribute to access the first element? For example:

```
>>>myVector = MyClassVector()
>>>foo1 = MyClass_c()
>>>foo2 = MyClass_c()
>>>foo3 = MyClass_c()
>>>myVector.push_back(foo1)
>>>myVector.push_back(foo2)
>>>myVector.push_back(foo3)
>>>it = myVector.begin()
```

This is what I get when I print the available attributes for an iterator:

```
['advance', 'copy', 'decr', 'distance', 'equal', 'incr', 'next', 'previous', 'this', 'value']
```

Obviously the iterator can't be used with "->" as in C++. How is the proper way to use this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Python for loop, but here's a simple example:

```
%module x

%{
#include <vector>
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
%template(MyVector) std::vector<int>;
```

Examples:

```
>>> import x
>>> v=x.MyVector([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> v
<x.MyVector; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< int > *' at 0x0000000002A7B030> >
>>> v[0]
1
>>> v[1]
2
>>> for i in v: print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
>>> i=v.begin()
>>> while i  != v.end():
...   print(i.next())
...
1
2
3
4
5
```

So you can do it, but the Python `for` loop is easier.